# Angularjs show element only if other input is not empty

Tags: forms, angularjs

Is there a way to show a dom element only if an input is not empty? on top of other restrictions such as valid and dirty.

This is my markup right now:

```
<div class="form-group user-config">
    <label for="upassword" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Parola</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 form-control-static">
        <button data-ng-show="!formShowChangePassword" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-ng-click="showChangePassword()">Modifica Parola</button>
        <div data-ng-show="formShowChangePassword" class="right-inner-addon">
            <i data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Parola trebuie sa aiba cel putin 8 caractere si sa contina litere mari si mici precum si cifre" data-ng-show="userConfigSettingsForm.upassword.$dirty && userConfigSettingsForm.upassword.$invalid" class="fa fa-fw fa-exclamation-circle input-error-icon"></i>
            <input data-ng-blur="formCheckEmptyPassword($event)" data-ng-minlength="8" data-ng-pattern="/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,255}$/" data-ng-required="formDbData.UserId == 0" class="form-control input-sm" name="upassword" id="upassword" placeholder="Parola" data-ng-model="formDbData.Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-show="userConfigSettingsForm.upassword.$valid && userConfigSettingsForm.upassword.$dirty && formShowChangePassword" class="col-sm-12 form-control-static" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label pull-left label-trimite-email">Trimite email catre</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right form-control-static">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" ng-model="formSendEmail.user" btn-checkbox>User</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" ng-model="formSendEmail.admin" btn-checkbox>Administrator</button>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want the second div in `div.form-group` to only be shown when the upassword input is valid, dirty and not empty. So far it works for the first 2. I tried to check the model (formDbData.Password) but that doesn't get updated unless the input is valid

the function formCheckEmptyPassword just changes formShowChangePassword to false if the input is empty. Also showChangePassword() changes it to true.

Answer (score 0):

`formDbData.Password` is not empty when `userConfigSettingsForm.upassword.$valid` AND input field is not empty.

Therefore you could simplify your logic like this:

```
<div data-ng-show="userConfigSettingsForm.upassword.$dirty && formDbData.Password"
```

But I think what you need is removing your `userConfigSettingsForm.upassword.$valid` condition

```
<div data-ng-show="userConfigSettingsForm.upassword.$dirty && formShowChangePassword"
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HHAp9syr7r8Op2cmQ0h7?p=preview)

Comment: Actually just adding `&& formDbData.Password` seems to work. I swear I tried that earlier.

Comment: @Bogdan: your requirements seem conflict with each other when you want both `userConfigSettingsForm.upassword.$valid` and not empty (`don't need to be valid`)

Comment: I would think $valid includes not empty (considering it has minlength 8 and the pattern requires at least 8 characters. At least theoretically but it seems angular's implementation considers an empty field always valid

Comment: @Bogdan: I mean your code works correctly as you describe in your question. Maybe you need something different like removing your `userConfigSettingsForm.upassword.$valid` condition